# Why does `yield from` in a generator expression yield `None`s?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield, generator-expression

I have the following code:

```
import itertools
for c in ((yield from bin(n)[2:]) for n in range(10)):
    print(c)
```

The output is:

```
 0
 None
 1
 None
 1
 0 
 None
 1
 1
 None
```

... etc. Why do the `None`s appear? If I instead have:

```
def hmm():
 for n in range(10):
     yield from bin(n)[2:]

for c in hmm():
    print(c)
```

Then I get what I would expect:

```
0
1
1
0
1
1
```

... etc. Further, is there a way to write it as the generator expression to get the same result as the latter?

Comment: It would be nice to change your example to one that doesn't use an infinite loop.  Why not change `itertools.count` to `range(10)` or something?

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html): "Additionally, the subgenerator is allowed to return with a value, and the value is made available to the delegating generator."

Comment: in your first code you mix python2 and 3 specifique syntax, you should remove the print statement and make it a function call

Comment: @BrenBarn: Well I wouldn't necessarily need a generator then! My use case is specifically making an infinite generator

Comment: @Claudiu: Yes, but the `None`s are still generated regardless of how long the source generator is.  Your question doesn't say "how do I make an infinite generator".  If you're asking about why the Nones are created, you should try to create a simple example focusing on that issue.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Ah yes good point, fixed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`yield` is an expression, and its value is whatever is sent into the generator with `send`.  If nothing is sent in, the value of `yield` is None.  In your example `yield from` yields the values from the list, but the value of the `yield from` expression itself is None, which is yielded at each iteration of the enclosing generator expression (i.e., every value of `range(10)`).

Your example is equivalent to:

```
def hmm():
    for n in range(10):
        yield (yield from bin(n)[2:])

for item in hmm():
    print(item)
```

Note the extra `yield`.

You will always have this issue if you try to use `yield` in a generator expression, because the generator expression already yields its target values, so if you add an explicit `yield`, you are adding an extra expression (the `yield` expression) whose value will also be output in the generator.  In other words, something like `(x for x in range(5))` already yields the numbers in `range(5)`; if you do something like `((yield x) for x in range(5))`, you're going to get the values of the `yield` expression in addition to the numbers.

As far as I know, there is no way to get the simple `yield from` behavior (without extra Nones) using a generator comprehension.  For your case, I think you can achieve what you want by using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
for c in itertools.chain.from_iterable(bin(n)[2:] for n in range(10)):
    print(c)
```

(Edit: I realized you can get the `yield from` behavior in a generator comprehension by using nested `for` clauses: `x for n in range(10) for x in bin(n)[2:]`.  However, I don't think this is any more readable than using `itertools.chain`.)