# Difference between list comprehension and generator comprehension with `yield` inside

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

What is the difference between list comprehensions and generator comprehensions with `yield` inside?  Both return a generator object (`listcomp` and `genexpr` respectively), but upon full evaluation the latter adds what seem to be rather superfluous `None`s.

```
>>> list([(yield from a) for a in zip("abcde", itertools.cycle("12"))])
['a', '1', 'b', '2', 'c', '1', 'd', '2', 'e', '1']

>>> list(((yield from a) for a in zip("abcde", itertools.cycle("12"))))
['a', '1', None, 'b', '2', None, 'c', '1', None, 'd', '2', None, 'e', '1', None]
```

How come?  What is the scientific explanation?

Comment: @Alik, @Antti Haapala, please, remove the "duplicate" marking.  This question asks about the behavior using a `yield from` Python statement.  The linked "duplicate" answer asks a similar question about `yield` Python statement.  These two statements are distinct.  And since `yield from` was only recently added to the language it is quite natural that there are new unexpected behaviors which it produces.  This should result in some questions which, while they may look similar to the questions about `yield`, are not the same questions as the ones about `yield`.

Comment: are you still looking for an answer to your question?

Comment: The first case is actually throwing away the result of the list comprehension. The result is from the side-effect of the comprehension, caused by ``yield from a``.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: A generator expression uses an implicit `yield`, which returns `None` from the `yield from` expression.

There are actually *two* things behaving differently here. Your list comprehension is actually thrown away...

- **Once again with clarity**

Understanding this is easiest if you transform the expressions to equivalent functions. For clarity, let's write this out:

```
listcomp = [<expr> for a in b]
def listfunc():
    result = []
    for a in b:
        result.append(<expr>)
    return result

gencomp = (<expr> for a in b)
def genfunc():
    for a in b:
        yield <expr>
```

To replicate the initial expressions, the key is to replace `<expr>` with `(yield from a)`. This is a simple textual replacement:

```
def listfunc():
    result = []
    for a in b:
        result.append((yield from a))
    return result

def genfunc():
    for a in b:
        yield (yield from a)
```

With `b = ((1,), (2,))`, we would expect the output `1, 2`. Indeed, both replicate the output of their respective expression/comprehension forms.

As explained [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979803/why-does-yield-from-in-a-generator-expression-yield-nones), `yield (yield from a)` should make you suspicious. However, `result.append((yield from a))` should make you cringe...

- **Yielding the answer**

Let's look at the generator first. Another rewrite makes it obvious what is going on:

```
def genfunc():
    for a in b:
        result = (yield from a)
        yield result
```

For this to be valid, `result` must have a value - namely `None`. The generator does **not** `yield` the `(yield from a)` expression, but its result. You only get the content of `a` as a side effect of evaluating the expression.

- **Returning to the question**

If you check the type of your "list comprehension", it is not `list` - it is `generator`. `<listcomp>` is just its name. Yes, that's not a Moon, that's a fully functional generator.

Remember how our transformation put a `yield from` inside a function? Yepp, that is how you define a generator!
Here is our function version, this time with `print` sprinkled on it:

```
def listfunc():
    result = []
    for a in b:
        result.append((yield from a))
        print(result[-1])
    print(result)
    return result
```

Evaluating `list(listfunc())` *prints* `None`, `None` (from the `append`), and `[None, None]` (from the `result`) and *yields* `1, 2`. Your actual list contains those `None` that sneaked into the generator as well! However, it is thrown away and the result is again just a side effect. This is what actually happens:

- A generator is created upon evaluating the list comprehension/`listfunc`.
- Feeding it to `list` iterates over it...

  - `yield from a` yields the values of `a` to `list` *and returns* `None` to the comprehension/`listfunc`
  - `None` is stored in the result list
- At the end of the iteration...

  - `return` raises `StopIteration` with a value of `[None, None]`
  - The `list` constructor ignores this and throws the value away
- **Moral of this story**

Don't use `yield from` inside of comprehensions. It does not do what you think it does.

Comment: `yield` in comprehensions and genexps is going to be [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#deprecated) in Python 3.7 and forbidden in Python 3.8, because it's so confusing and violates invariants like "list comprehensions evaluate to lists".

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `yield from` expression is `None`. The fact that your second example is a generator expression means that it is already implicitly yielding from the iterator, so it will also yield the value of the `yield from` expression. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26979908/5960561) for a more detailed answer.

Comment: It doesn't explain the difference between `yield from` evaluation in generator comprehension and list comprehension though

Comment: list comprehension has no implicit yield so this behaviour doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Both examples are deprecated in Python 3.8 because of the confusion and throw `SyntaxError: 'yield' inside list comprehension`. See the [buglog for 3.8 for the release notes](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.8.html#changes-in-python-behavior).